# Windows: how to retrieve the exact port used by a service in Python

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, port, netstat

I am new to the Windows command line, and I am wondering if there is a command that can retrieve the exact port used by a service by name. Ideally I'd like to do it with Python, but if it has to be a bash command that's fine too.

My example: I am running a service that connects to a port within a specific range. Every time the service restarts it uses a new random port. I want to automate the way it finds the port, so I can run the code that has to listen to this port and connect to the service automatically without having to manually specify which port the service is using.

I am able to get the list of services and the ports they're connected to using the following command:

```
> netstat -ab
```

as shown in this screenshot:

[image: console screenshot]

How can I retrieve the port for the service "naoqi-bin.exe" with state "ESTABLISHED"?

Comment: I see two instances of `naoqi-bin` with `ESTABLISHED` states. Do you want both of them?

Answer (score 0):

You have the information you need right there in the `netstat` output... why not just read that and fish it out?  Something like this might work...

```
import subprocess

def get_naoqi_port():
    netstat = subprocess.Popen(["netstat", "-ab"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    for outline in netstat.stdout:
        if "naoqi-bin.exe" in outline and "ESTABLISHED" in outline:
            netstat.kill()    # no need for more output
            return int(outline.split(None, 3)[1].rsplit(":", 1)[-1])
```

Comment: The executable name in brackets is on a line following the connection info (protocol, local address, foreign address, state), not the same line. In this case the executable is listed on the next line, but in general there may be a service name listed on the 2nd line in the group, with the bracketed executable name listed on the 3rd line. Also, in general use `-n` to list numeric ports instead of well-known names, such as 443 instead of "https".

Comment: For Python 3, either call `subprocess.Popen` with `universal_newlines=True` to decode the output as ANSI, or use `bytes` literals such as `b"naoqi-bin.exe"`.

Comment: Hi @kindall , the issue with this is that running netstat in a cmd "requires elevation". I guess there is no easy way in my python script to run subprocess in an elevated cmd?